# Estimation of variance in simple linear regression: why $n-2$ in the denominator rather than $n-1$?

Tags: regression, anova, residuals, degrees-of-freedom

In a simple linear regression, in the estimation of 
$$\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat y_i)^2}{n-1}$$

why is the denominator $n-2$ and not $n-1$?

Comment: Basically, this is because $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i$. That is, you lost two degrees of freedom when you estimated the intercept and the slope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are dividing the Residual Sum of Squares by the residual degrees of freedom ($df$).
The residual $df$ is the number of cases minus the number of parameters in the mean function.

So for simple regression the residual $df=n-2$